# OCR on pages containing both text and images in Acrobat XI Pro

Tags: adobe-acrobat, ocr

Why does Acrobat XI Pro not allow an OCR scan on pages containing both images and renderable text? The sample PDF in the screenshot was created from an MS Word doc. The first line was typed out; the second line is a screenshot of a separate doc.

This seems like an arbitrary limitation. Is there a good reason why Acrobat can't just skip renderable text and scan everything else? Is there an easy way to run OCR on just a portion of a page?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is an arbitrary limitation, and it won't be fixed in Acrobat XI (anymore).

Best practice is to export the page as TIFF, and reload it into Acrobat. Now, everything is image, and therefore, the page can be OCRd.